# System.Security.Permissions missing when invoking JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: serialization, json.net, openapi, .net-framework-version, openapi-generator

I have generated the Csharp client for WebAPICore using the OpenAPI generator.
I am getting the local response as 200 with ResponseStatus:OK
But while type casting the response as shown below:

```
try {
  return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, type, serializerSettings);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new ApiException(500, e.Message);
}
```

AT `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, type, serializerSettings);`. It is having the following issue:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried installing the NuGet Package with version: 4.0.3.0 and added the reference to Project, but still facing the same.